# looping through a column and deleting rows that do not belong

Tags: c#, algorithm, excel, interop

I am using c# to connect to excel using INTEROP.

If do not know INTEROP, this shouldnt stop you from answering this question. I am racking my brain trying to figure out an algorithm for the following:

Suppose I have a string `string1="ALEX"`

I have a list:

```
AAAA
ALEX
ALEX
LIZA
LIZA
```

Or the list can be:

```
ALEX
ALEX
ALEX
LIZA
NANCY
```

I need to delete all occurrences of strings that are `NOT== ALEX`

I do not want to do this one by one because it takes way too long

The list is ALWAYS sorted and i just want to get the starting positions and ending positions   in the list of the strings that I need to get rid of

I have a loop that goes through every row and inside the loop:

```
if (cell.Value2.ToString()!= email && !foundStart) {
    startpos = rCnt;
    foundStart = true;
}
else if (cell.Value2.ToString() != email && foundStart) {
    endPos = rCnt;
    deleteRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + startpos + ":" + "CO" + endPos, Type.Missing);
    deleteRange = deleteRange.EntireRow;
    deleteRange.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
    foundStart = false;
}
```

This is not working at all. please help! your guidance can be in terms of the simple algorithm or the specific code i can use

Comment: please note that in order to delete anything i need to give  a RANGE to delete instead of deleting elements one by one

Comment: IF the list is AAAA, ALEX, ALEX, LIZA it is fine to delete the first one and just give a range of 1:1, but if it is AAA, AAA, ALEX, then i need to delete 1:2

Comment: Perhaps I'm in error, but that range doesn't convince me. startPos and endPos are supposed to be the row numbers right? And this gives, for example, a get_Range("A1:CO3")? Is this a valid range?

Comment: yes thats fine that is a valid range, i just simplified my question

Answer (score 0):

If the list is always sorted, use a binary search to find the elements in the list to be deleted.

```
function binarySearch (int lowRow, int highRow, int currentRow, string searchValue, string[] values) {
    if values[currentRow] < searchValue
        return binarySearch (lowRow, currentRow, (currentRow - lowRow) / 2, searchValue, values);
    else if values[currentRow] > searchValue
        return binarySearch (currentRow, highRow, (highRow - currentRow) / 2, searchValue, values);
    else
        return currentRow;
}

var searchTerm = "ALEX";
var foundRow = binarySearch(1, listFromExcel.RowCount, listFromExcel.RowCount/2, searchTerm, listFromExcel);

var lowRow = foundRow;
var highRow = foundRow;

while (listFromExcel[lowRow] == searchTerm) 
    lowRow--;
lowRow++;

while (listFromExcel[highRow] == searchTerm)
    highRow++;
highRow++;

listFromExcel.DeleteRange(lowRow, highRow);
```

Comment: thanks so much! how can i use a binary sort to delete elements?

Comment: The binary search is to find the range of rows to delete.  Once you have the range to delete, use that range for deleting.

Comment: More specifically, once you hit a match with binary search, then go row by row up and down until you no longer have a match.  Record the row number of the first and last element, then use that range for deleting.

Comment: if the list is sorted, I would instead concentrate on finding the continuous range of elements you DO want to keep. Then determine the other ranges to remove based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the contents of the range to a two-dimensional array. Do the work against the array (*much faster*). Then transfer the array back to the worksheet.